# I am unable to save my data from a form

Tags: plugin-development, forms

For some reason I am unable to save the data from my form:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'example_menu_settings' );

/** Step 1. */
function example_menu_settings() {
    add_options_page( 'example Plugin Options', 'example', 'manage_options', 'example-settings', 'example_plugin_options' );
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'register_example_settings' );
}

/** Step 3. */
function example_plugin_options() {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )  {
        wp_die( __( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.' ) );
    }

    $client_id = get_option('example_client_id', '');
    $secret = get_option('example_secret', '');

    echo '<div class="wrap">
      <h2>example Plugin Settings</h2>
      <br><br>
        <form method="post" action="options.php">';
        settings_fields( 'example-settings-group' );
        do_settings_sections( 'example-settings-group' );
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="option_page" value="general"><input type="hidden" name="action" value="update"><input type="hidden" id="_wpnonce" name="_wpnonce" value="103f63adef"><input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/example-Blog/wp-admin/options-general.php">
          <table class="form-table">
            <tbody>
            <tr valign="top">
            <th scope="row"><label for="example_client_id">Client ID</label></th>
            <td><input name="example_client_id" type="text" id="example_client_id" value="' . $client_id . '" class="regular-text">
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr valign="top">
            <th scope="row"><label for="example_secret">Secret</label></th>
            <td><input name="example_secret" type="text" id="example_secret" value="' . $secret . '" class="regular-text">
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2" class="description" style="padding: 25px 0 10px 0;">Your keys is found inside your <a href="https://example.com/user" target="_blank">example account settings</a>.</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <br>
            <button id="example-test-connection" class="button">Test connection</button>';
            echo submit_button();
        echo '</form>
      </div>';
}

function register_example_settings() { // whitelist options
  register_setting( 'example-settings-group', 'example_client_id' );
  register_setting( 'example-settings-group', 'example_secret' );
}
```

Here is the error I get:

```
Are you sure you want to do this?

Please try again.
```

This is the /wp-admin/options.php page.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a hidden field named `_wpnonce` in your form including hard coded value, plus another field named `_wp_http_referrer`. You better remove these, and let 
`settings_fields()` generate them. (it should already do so).

Comment: Give http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces a look. Agreed with @jörn.